# Logical Paradoxes

Tags: logic, paradoxes

**Is the answer to the question "Is the answer to the outer question 'Yes'?" 'No'?**

Both the inner and outer questions are Yes/No questions.

Comment: What's **your** question?

Comment: Yes, that **is** my question.

Comment: @Ahmad: you want the answer in Yes or No.

Comment: Yes, that is clearly visible from the question.

Comment: Please expand your post to comment more fully on what you are asking and what you would like others to answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\getsto}{\gets\hspace{-2ex}\to}$
Let $X$ be the answer to the outer question. 
Let $Y$ be the answer to the inner question.

The answer to the inner question *confirms* the answer to the outer question.   $Y\getsto X$

The answer to the outer question *contradicts* the answer to the inner question.   $X\getsto\neg Y$

That infers that $X\getsto \neg X$.   So, clearly, the outer question is *inconsistent*.

> The answer to the question is *not* the answer to the question.